# Putting labels on a complete graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Hi guys  I have this picture and I want to make it better by putting names on the edge. For example I wanted to make the edge connecting 1 and 4 to say `$\theta_1 \theta_4$` and so on for all the edges.Thank you so much I really appreciate the help and time of anyone who reads this!!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
  \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
    \pgfmathparse{(\x-1)*360/4}
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.15cm] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {\x};
  } 
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 1] in {1,...,4}{%
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{%
     \path (N-\x) edge[ultra thin,-] (N-\y);

  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting `node`s along the edge. Here a suboptimal, but automated solution. Of course you can put `edge`s and `node`s manually and then choose, where the `node`s should appear as given for the red `node`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(\x-1)*360/4}
        \node [draw,circle,inner sep=0.15cm] (N-\x) at (\pgfmathresult:1.4cm) {\x};
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}{%
        % because there is no need to draw an edge to the starting node itself
        % start at index 2 in the second loop
        \foreach \y in {2,...,4}{%
            % also the edge should only be drawn, if \x is smaller than \y
            \ifnum \x<\y
                \path (N-\x) edge [ultra thin,-]
                    node [auto,swap] {$\theta_{\x} \theta_{\y}$}
                        (N-\y);
            \fi
        }
    }
    % edge placed by hand
    \path (N-1) edge [ultra thin,-]
        node [auto,red] {$\theta_{1} \theta_{4}$}
            (N-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]